# Specific number validation?

Tags: javascript, validation, numbers, set

Is it possible to validate a field to a specific set of numbers using javascript? Say for example in a postcode field you can only enter four numbers to be be accepted e.g. 2747,2750, 2753, 2760, 2777. Any other number will be returned as false. I have done a bit of searching around but i can't seem to find anything of use for this specific situation and i'm quite knew to javascript so any sort of help would be great.

Comment: Yep, it is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Josh I haven't tried anything yet, i can't find any useful information on this specific situation on how i could do it, is there a page where i could find something helpful that you would know off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be really simple:

[**Live DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/alexflav23/JtKQp/)

1. Create a list of your numbers
2. Create an `Object` with every number as a key and whatever as a property.
3. If they come from the server, send and parse them as JSON.// skip
4. In JS, `var validNumbers = JSON.parse(serverResponse);` // skip
5. Use an `Object`, not an `Array`. `Array.prototype.indexOf` is slower and needs polyfill.
6. Object property access is O(1) and universally supported.
7. Your object looks like this: `var validNumbers = {"2747": "2747", etc..}`
8. Get the input from the user.
9. `if (typeof validNumbers[userInput] !== undefined) {//valid} else {//invalid}`

Comment: So i would need a database for this? there is no way to use some form of array?

Comment: Just need a bit more help with the code you showed me, when i entered it into my page it doesn't seem to work at all, i don't need to call the function do i?

Comment: ah cool that fixed it! Just one more thing would i be able to change the alert message? do i just enter my own message in the alert line?

Comment: Thank so much, you've really been helpful!

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.getElementById("entry_834285895").value;
    if ((x != 3242 )&&(x != 2342 )&&(x != 2343 )&&(x != 1111 )) {
        document.getElementById("um").innerHTML = ('Invalid');
  document.getElementById("um").style.color = 'Red';
    }
 else {
        document.getElementById("um").innerHTML = ('Valid');
  document.getElementById("um").style.color = 'Green';
    }
 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p>Valid numbers:<br> 3242<br>2342<br>2343<br>1111
<form name="myForm" action="" target="hiddenFrame"
onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post" >
Name: <input id="entry_834285895" type="text" name="fname">
 
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
<div id="um"></div>
</form>
<iframe name="hiddenFrame" style="display:none;"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```